# How To Find Implementing Types in WebStorm and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

If I have the following :

```
  class MyLabelValue implements  LabelledValue{
    label : string;
    constructor(labelArg : string){
      this.label = labelArg
    }
  }
```

I would like to be able to `right click` on LabelledValue and find all other classes that implement it. Is this possible with WebStorm?

And if so, what other type discovery commands are there? For example `extract interface` and `implement interface` would be really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Right-click | Go To | Implementation(s) or (Ctrl + Alt + B for default key bindings)

[Refactoring for TypeScript](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/typescript-support.html):
*Common refactoring procedures, such as extract method , inline, rename/move, etc.
TypeScript-specific refactoring procedures, such as change signature, extract parameter, extract variable.*

in addition to those available for JavaScript and TypeScript [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/javascript-specific-refactorings.html).